# Adding AJAX-enabled WCF Service to the Solution throws an error

Tags: ajax, wcf, wcf-configuration

I am just trying to learn Ajax enabled WCF service, when I try to create a new web application and add new item "AJAX-enabled WCF Service" I get an error message that "The extension of type 'System.ServiceModel.Configuration.WebScriptEnablingElement, System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not registered in the extension collection 'behaviorExtensions'.

I had .net2.0/VS2005 and then I installed VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem after I reinstalled .Net 3.5. Thanks to Social.Microsoft forum.